# Are scala Objects and Collections immutable by default?

Tags: scala

As a noob to Scala, someone mentioned that all scala objects and collections immutable by default. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

It is not true.

Though `immutable` is one feature of `FP` (function programming), there are mutable usages in `Scala`. For instance,

```
val greetStrings: Array[String] = new Array[String](3)
```

> You can change the elements of that Array[String] over time, so the array itself is mutable.

As for `Sets` and `Maps`, `Scala` provides both immutable and mutable varieties, and the immutable is as default.

[image]

The inside story of how the immutable one is default :

the `Scala` pre-defined the

```
type Map[A, +B] = immutable.Map[A, B]
type Set[A]     = immutable.Set[A]
```

in `Predef.scala`.

Answer (score -1):

Sequences are the only collection NOT immutable as default and the reason is in fact to allow array to be constructed